# Jquery Render currency from table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, rendering

This is a table which display transactions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hK7i.png)

```
<tr>            
    <td><?php echo $row[id]; ?></td>                        
    <td><?php echo $row[Request_Date]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[Partner]; ?></td>                       
    <td><?php echo $row[Package]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[Qty]; ?></td>
    <td id="amount"><?php echo $row[Amount]; ?></td>                        
</tr>
```

```
<script>
$("tr").find("#amount").each(function() {
        var data = $(this).html();
        $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, symbol).display(data);
    });
 </script>
```

Now I want to add an enhancement: format the amount using Indonesian format, so for example 25000 will be displayed as "Rp 25.000";

A Google search pointed me to renderers. I added the render part into my code, and well it doesn't change the formatting. What is wrong here?

Comment: What have you tried so far? When is the script being run?

Comment: This question is about JS, so please a) don't post PHP but the final HTML b) provide a [mre] is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script>
    let x = document.querySelectorAll("#amount"); 
    for (let i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) { 
        let num = Number(x[i].innerHTML) 
                  .toLocaleString('en'); 
        x[i].innerHTML = "Rp "+ num; 
        x[i].classList.add("currSign"); 
    } 
</script>
```